# Does anyone know the part number for the package with marking code "MAAC A65A"?

Tags: identification

It's a 8-pin, MSOP Package component.

[image]

Can you provide a datasheet for it?

Comment: Could you provide a picture? Or maybe a little context? Where did the part come from? What are you planning on using it for?

Comment: it comes from a PCB which we bought from SIEMENS, one hearing aid device. I'm trying to reverse the functionality of this component so that can use it in my final year project. I'm planning on designing one BT transimitter and receiver. I need the data sheet of it.

Comment: as new user can't upload image, i post my image at link:http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/001gsd.png/ thank you for response, any help appriciates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I applied some Google-fu and I found the datasheet for this device: [LMH6643](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmh6642.pdf).

It's a Low Power, 130 MHz, 75 mA Rail-to-Rail Output Amplifier from Texas Instruments.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lol, beat me to it, I just took that exact same (first) clip of the datasheet - +1 for having faster google-fu :-)

Comment: @OliGlaser If you found the same datasheet, than it's definitely the right IC! :-)

Comment: Hi all, thank you for help.. yup just wonder why i can't find the datasheet same through google shearch? any advice for me on how to become a google-fu? forget about faster or slower Lol...

Comment: @user15304 I just searched for `A65A MSOP` and a lot of results pointed to the `LMH6643` IC. If you really want to become a master of Google-fu, I recommend [this course from Google on power searching](http://www.powersearchingwithgoogle.com/) :-)